# How to create a routing on windows server A lookup

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, routing, dns-zone

I created A lookup that when someone types the url it resolves to an IP Address(e.g. 18.1.5.9).
Now I would like to put a routing that when the above IP address comes route via another IP(10.1.2.2) address.
So the idea is when the (18.1.5.9) IP address comes route it via (10.1.2.2).
I am using windows server 2012. Can someone please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `route` command to set a static route.

Using your example IPs:
`route add 18.1.5.9 mask 255.255.255.255 10.1.2.2`

You can read more about the Windows `route` command here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/route_ws2008